# How to handle multiple htttp requests on Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a function that attempts to make 3 requests chained together like this:

```
showProfileDetails() {
  this.getUserInfo(this.currentUser.id).pipe(
    mergeMap(e =>
      this.getAccounts(this.currentUser.id)
    ),
    mergeMap(e =>
      this.getPayments(this.currentUser.id)
    )
  ).subscribe(data =>
    console.log('first attempt on observables: ', data)
  )
}
```

What  I want to do is retreive the data from every call synchronously and store it in a variable so I can then render the data in the DOM.

But all I'm getting is the data from the last call, which btw returns an error, how could I handle this error without stopping this process? thanks in advance, I'm new to Angular.

Comment: You can store the data from each response even if they are asyn calls... Let me show you that in a while, give me 15 mins.

Comment: .you can use redux

Comment: I would very much apppreciate it

Answer (score 6):

you can use forkjoin for handling multiple http request like this way using RxJs:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';

getVehicles(): Observable<any> {
  const user = this.http.get(USER_ENDPOINT).map(res => res.json());
  const account = this.http.get(ACCOUNT_ENDPOINT).map(res => res.json());
  const payment = this.http.get(PAYMENT_ENDPOINT).map(res => res.json());

  return Observable.forkJoin([user, account, payment])
     .map(responses => {
        // responses[0] => user
        // responses[1] => account
        // responses[2] => payment
     });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Made this StackBlitz check this out:

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-async-calls-httpclient
>
> https://angular-async-calls-httpclient.stackblitz.io {Full Page View}

Files you need to check:

- services > http.service.ts {this contains the method for using GET
  request}
- services > users.service.ts {this contains the methods}
- app.component.ts

In app.component.ts file in ngOnInit you can see that I have async calls which I have made equivalent to some variable which I can now console or use in my template.